# Sending key Value to server in IOS

Tags: http-post, ios7.1

```
Key is>  hi
Value is> hello
```

I need to send this value to server.Consider my url is `https://mywebsite/myserver/upload`
How to send these value to server in IOS by making HTTP POST method.

Comment: what do you want to send it as? a request body or as header field ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can send key pair value as a part of your request body

```
    NSString *myKeyValuePairString = @"hi=hello";
    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[myKeyValuePairString UTF8String] length:[myKeyValuePairString length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://mywebsite/myserver/upload"]]; 
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
```

if as a part of header

```
[request setValue:@"hello" forHTTPHeaderField:@"hi"];
```

Comment: what this line says NSString *myKeyValuePainString = @"hi=hello"; especially you wrote hi=hello.

Comment: I'm assuming this is how you want to the key pair value as part of your request body.. If you want to send it as an xml you can send in an xml format.